# Laravel Merge to merge same ID

Tags: laravel

Hello I have query that is already working and it combines two queries, but what I need is to combine the same `product _id` and not output it into another array.

Here is my code:

```
$first = DB::table('delivery_receipt_detail');
$first->join('delivery_receipts', 'delivery_receipt_detail.delivery_receipt_id', '=', 'delivery_receipts.id');
$first->where(function ($first) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
    $first->whereBetween('delivery_receipts.posting_date', [new Carbon($start_date), new Carbon($end_date)]);
    $first->orWhereDate('delivery_receipts.posting_date', '=', new Carbon($start_date));
    $first->orWhereDate('delivery_receipts.posting_date', '=', new Carbon($end_date));
});
$first->groupBy('delivery_receipt_detail.product_id');
$first->select('delivery_receipt_detail.product_id as delivery_product_id', DB::raw('SUM(product_qty) as delivery_product_qty'));
$result_one = $first->get();

//Sales
$query = DB::table('sale_detail');
$query->join('sales', 'sale_detail.sale_id', '=', 'sales.id');
$query->where(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
    $query->whereBetween('sales.posting_date', [new Carbon($start_date), new Carbon($end_date)]);
    $query->orWhereDate('sales.posting_date', '=', new Carbon($start_date));
    $query->orWhereDate('sales.posting_date', '=', new Carbon($end_date));
});

$query->groupBy('sale_detail.product_id');
$query->select('sale_detail.product_id as sales_product_id', DB::raw('SUM(product_qty) as sales_product_qty'));
$test = $query->get();

$merged = $result_one->merge($test);

$result = $merged->all();

return $result;
```

and my result is this:

```
 [
    {
    "delivery_product_id": "1",
    "delivery_product_qty": 4
    },
    {
    "delivery_product_id": "2",
    "delivery_product_qty": 1
    },
    {
    "sales_product_id": "1",
    "sales_product_qty": "3"
    },
    {
    "sales_product_id": "2",
    "sales_product_qty": "3"
    }
 ]
```

What I need is this output

```
[
    {
    "product_id": "1",
    "delivery_product_qty": 4
    "sales_product_qty": "3"
    },
    {
    "product_id": "2",
    "delivery_product_qty": 1
    "sales_product_qty": "3"
    }

 ]
```

I need to combine this and merging the same product_id and show their different quantities.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you calling each method separately instead of chaining the methods together?

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I think you only need to specify the same name for the `product_id` when selecting and `->merge` will do the rest

```php
$first = DB::table('delivery_receipt_detail')
    ->select('delivery_product_id as product_id', 'delivery_product_qty');
// ...

$query = DB::table('sale_detail')
    ->select('sales_product_id as product_id', 'sales_product_qty');
// ...

$merged = $result_one->merge($test);
```

Comment: it will only combine two queries but not combining into one array